# Macvim Surround Plugin

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm fairly new to Vim in general but I'm having trouble with the Surround plugin. Most of the standard options seem to work but when I highlight text in visual mode, switch back to edit mode and press 's' to surround with a character the 's' key simply ends up removing the highlighted text and puts the editor back into insert mode.

After digging into this, it seems logical since this is the behavior that the 's' should have within that mode but then how do I surround selected text using the plugin?

Answer (score 3):

Highlight your text in visual mode, as in press <kbd>v</kbd> and select your text (like <kbd>viw</kbd> to select the word your cursor is inside, and type, for example <kbd>s'</kbd> to surround it with single quotes. Just don't drop out of visual mode.

Comment: After playing around with it for a bit I discovered what I was doing wrong. Hitting "s" dropped me out of visual mode and into insert whereas "S" performed the surround as expected. Turns out all I was missing the capitalization.

Comment: That's odd, lowercase s performs the surround for me

Comment: I think this is a [recent change](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/commit/c9120390d8e51e42faef420f83ef0001a20643f3) in surround.